# Can I prevent myself from deleting a file?

Tags: permissions, chmod

It seems logical that a user ought to be able to tell himself that he is not allowed to delete a file under his own ownership.

I'd like to take away my own permission to delete a file. Can I do this without chmodding it as root? Can I just say, "I am not allowed to delete this file, until I explicitly give myself permission to delete it"?

Thanks.

Comment: Deleting a file is an operation on the containing directory. Can you change the permissions of the containing directory?

Comment: @muru to my surprise, yeah. `chmod 0444` seemed to do the trick. Throw it down there and Ill accept it as an answer. I feel silly for not just trying that in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting a file is an operation on the containing directory. If you don't have write permissions on that directory, you cannot delete files within it. Note: you won't be able to delete *any* file within it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you make the file immutable with `chattr`, it'll stick around:

```
chattr +i your.file
```

You can [read more about the features of `chattr` with the manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/chattr.1.html)

Comment: `chattr +i foo` `chattr: Operation not permitted while setting flags on foo`

Comment: Slap a `sudo` on there. You'll keep ownership of the file.

Comment: Is it otherwise impossible then? I meant this question for changing your own permissions without using root.

Comment: chattr +i filea --- rm filea rm: cannot remove 'filea': Operation not permitted --- chattr -i filea --- rm -i filea --- rm: remove regular empty file 'filea'? y --- so it can stop you from deleting a file

Comment: Yes it looks like you need root